# Spring security : css is missing or not loaded in a web browser

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-security, resources, loading

i am using spring security 3.0 . In spring-security.xml , i have a  1 problem when display login page. The login.jsp of CSS is not load or missing in the web browser. so please solve this problem.. Any help i appreciated u.

my spring-security.xml code is given below..

```
     <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">

  <http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.html" access="permitAll" />
     <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />

   <intercept-url pattern="/accessdenied" access="permitAll"  />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
   <form-login login-page="/login.html" default-target-url="/firstwelcome.html"  />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" /> 
  </http>


  <authentication-manager  alias="authenticationManager">  
      <authentication-provider>  
        <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
              users-by-username-query="
              SELECT strUSERNAME, strPASSWORD, CASE blENABLED WHEN 1 THEN 'true' ELSE             'false' END 'ENABLED' 
      FROM TBLUSERS 
      WHERE strUSERNAME=?;"

    authorities-by-username-query="
     SELECT strUSERNAME, strROLENAME 
     FROM TBLUSERS
     WHERE strUSERNAME=?;"

     />
  </authentication-provider>  
  </authentication-manager>  



 </beans:beans>
```

and Header of the my login.jsp is given below

```
           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">
```

in above login.jsp  use link tag to call the css..
but unfortunately is not call ..``.plz... help me for calling the login.css file .
Any help i appreciated u.

Thanks

Comment: post your project structure

Comment: in web-content folder   1)css 2)images 2) Meta-INF 3) WEB-INF                  ..IN  CSS FOLDER login.css                 WEB-INF FOLDER IN 1)JSP 2)LIB 3)springservlet.xml 4)springsecurity.xml

Comment: As you views will inside `web-inf` , why dont you try `./` before your path ?

Comment: in   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/login.css">      ?

Comment: Yes . does that loads ?

Comment: login.jsp will call successfully but it's css (login.css) will not called.. so strucutre of login is not loaded

Comment: Can you post the configuration file for spring security?

Comment: ok... i respost ..u see my full  configuration file

Comment: so where is the problem..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your spring servlet write code like this

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
```

paste your css in resource folder.

```
  resources -> css -> style.css
  resources folder inside **webapp**
```

and access using

```
<link href="<c:url value="resources/css/style.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

I am sure about this it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add this line to `spring-security.xml` to allow this css

```
<intercept-url pattern="/css/login.css" access="permitAll"/>
```

so your `spring-security.xml` will be

```
<http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.html" access="permitAll" />
     <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />

   <intercept-url pattern="/css/login.css" access="permitAll"/>
   <intercept-url pattern="/accessdenied" access="permitAll"  />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
   <form-login login-page="/login.html" default-target-url="/firstwelcome.html"  />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" /> 
  </http>
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add following in java config class (instead of security driven by XML config) which extends 
`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`
Assuming your resources are in /resources/content
`http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/resources/content/**").permitAll()`